# How can I get the SMTP host name from email address?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, smtp

I was working on an application which would send emails automatically at specific time intervals to a valid email. Searching through the internet I found that most of the codes use the existing email accounts such as gmail.com to send email by logging in as an SMTP client. But my problem is that I won't be knowing the smtp server name of the users email(since the user is not generally aware of these things though he will be knowing the login/passoword). For example,

someone@gmail.com should give smtp.gmail.com and port number (465)

someone@nextek.net should give mail.nextek.net and port number (?)

someone@screaming.Net  smtp.tiscali.co.uk and port number (?)

I got the MX records using the domain name of the email address, but I realized that it actually gives the available incoming SMTP server names.

For example gmail.com would give gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com  along with four other server name if I ping using nslookup in command prompt.

Also what is the advantage of sending email by using an existing SMTP supporting email than sending directly by looking up the email server name through dns? Or is it not possible?

Correct me if I am wrong, since I am not much familiar with the protocols.

Comment: (1) Does your app receive email or get them from a source (such as Exchange or any other server) or you simply have the e-mail address? (2) I don't understand why you need to know the user's SMTP server. If you have their email address, that's all you need to send them a message. (3) What is the objective of your app: send e-mail to someone or send email *as* you were that person?

Comment: Assume you are the one using the App. The app would need to send email to your own email address automatically at specific time intervals. whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Let me ask you another question: this message that the app would send me, who would be the sender? Could it be *Automatic do not reply* or would it be myself?

Comment: It is Automatic do not reply. And this app should do this on any machine.

Comment: Well, then the best choice is: create an email account for your app (it could be even a free account, such as GMail or any other) and send this message from the server of that account. You don't need to know the receiver server, SMTP + DNS will do that for you. All you need to do is to send the message to a SMTP server, using your private credentials (your app account).

Comment: I cannot make an email for my app and do this. Rather the user would be using his own email account. I need to help the user in filling the details of his email server. For example once the email address is entered by the user all other details excluding the login and password should be automatically filled, especially the SMTP server name/port number. Is that possible?

Comment: Well, then you're saying that the **sender** of the message will be the user (that was my question on the second comment). I'm sorry, but I don't know if that is possible. Note that even Outlook doesn't do that. It tries the default (smtp. *domain* at port 25), but that's not always the case.

Comment: Even if you managed to pull this off on the coding side, most ISPs block outbound access to port 25, because what you want to do is precisely how spam zombies work; even if you can find out the server's name and address, you cannot connect. I would instead ask for the user's email sending preferences and put that in a config file, but it could get hairy. The Thunderbird account set-up wizard is a fairly good example of how you could do this, even if it's cumbersome to use in some places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not familiar with the protocols, it doesn't make sense for you to try to implement the protocol.

Generally, an application like yours doesn't need to worry about the details of the SMTP protocol. You would use an existing SMTP client library for your platform (I'm sure there is one for .NET you can use), and connect to an MTA (*your* MTA, not the recipient's), give it the email to send, and you're done. The MTA will take care of all the SMTP protocol details of figuring out how to get the email to the recipient.

Sending email is very similar to dropping a letter in the post box on the corner, and letting the post office figure out how to deliver it. You don't need to know which vehicle to put it on, or where the recipient's local post office distribution centre is, or any of those details.

You may choose to set up your own MTA using something like [Postfix](http://postfix.org), or you can send email through your own Gmail account (of course you'll need a Gmail account and password before Gmail will let you do that).